# Navigation bar fixed and absolute

Tags: html, css

So what I am trying to do is a navigation bar for my website. I decided to do a transparent background with a white fond, which works perfectly with the background picture. However, I want the bar to be visible also, when you scroll down the page. Thus I choose a fixed position for the navigation bar. But then again, if you scroll down to the section where there is white background and text, the (transparent & white) navigation bar becomes unreadable.

Is it possible to code two navigation bars? So one as I have it with an absolute position with a transparent background and the white font. As soon as you start to scroll, a new navigation bar, featuring the same content, but another background (eg. orange) should pop up. If so, how do I need to code that?

Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the easiest way to do this is with a a little bit of jQuery. 
Add this function:

It will create a new class that you can style your menu with.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= 900) { //Choose where on the page to add new class, here i'ts 900px from the page top
    $("nav").addClass("scrolling");
  } else {
    $("nav").removeClass("scrolling");
  }
});
```

CSS example:

```
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
}

nav.scrolling {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

Check it out here:
http://codepen.io/Winterfox/pen/QNrqRb

This way you don't have to create two almost exacty looking menues.